# Cannot come up with idea of practice example with RxJava (reactive programming)

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I began to study the reactive programming in Java. The theory of reading - is good, but to all settled, you also need to practice. The problem is that I can not come up with idea of example myself - I have a bad fantasy, and I'm not strong in this area yet, so alas ... And my request to you - come up, please, any non-trivial task, not associated with UI, which I would practice and reinforce knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently started using rxJava also. I suggest you try to implement a basic RESTful service that accesses a blocking resource, for example, a database. Use the Spring framework so you only need to concentrate on the request methods and the service methods that create, retrieve, update and delete (CRUD) items the database. Implement the CRUD methods as Observables.